# No sound in saved VLC stream

Tags: sound, vlc, streaming, stream

I'm tried to save stream using URL and it shows that there is audio track, but I don't hear anything. I used this:

```
vlc your_input_file_or_stream_here --sout=file/ps:go.mpg
```

Answer (score 1):

By using vlc you must trancode

See https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/ And https://gist.github.com/revolunet/320db93516ec19eb931b

A good alternative can be found with youtube-dl

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl    
youtube-dl -f best "<yourUrl>"
```